# Convert simple htaccess to web.config

Tags: asp.net, .htaccess, iis-7, web-config

I have htaccess and I want to write same functioning in web.config but don't have any knowledge of it, please help. Below is my htaccess code:

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteEngine on
       RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
       RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>`

Comment: don't forget to accept an answer if it helped you, as a basic courtesy towards others...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your tags I assume your using IIS7 URL Rewrite Module? If so then:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="all">
                <match url=".*"/>
                <action type="Redirect" url="app/webroot/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent"/>
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```